# Can I use Codeigniter for login and PHP for other functionality?

Tags: php, codeigniter, migration

My client has a website which is built on php (without any framework). The website is prone to attacks but almost 75% of the work is done. Keeping scalability in mind we want to migrate to codeigniter completely but the client wants an MVP to be released in 30 days. Can I use partial codeigniter and continue with the existing PHP code.
Thank You.

Comment: probably can, but you'll suffer for it.

Comment: @MarcB That is a temporary fix. Later on we write the entire code from scratch in codeigniter. We are running out of time and the website is already 75% built in php without any security norms taken.

Comment: 'without any security norms'? So you're gonna roll out a site that's 75% full of XSS and SQL injection holes? Please share the final url for the site, so we can blacklist it...

Comment: @MarcB I am scared to post the URL since it is seriously vulnerabe to all kinds of sql injection attacks. I have just got the poject and let me atleast fix few things and post the URL.

Comment: He was joking - I hope.

Comment: I was being sarcastic. If the site is COMPLETELY insecured, you should be screaming at your managers and clients to hold off on the rollout. Make noise now and rock the boat, rather than stand mute and become the scapegoat when the site INEVITABLY gets hacked later on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not given a lot of detail, but here goes.....

Firstly things that might be worth letting the SO community know about are:

- Some coding examples that exist with in the current project
- The type of application / web site that is being built
- What exactly you mean by scalability (10s or 100s or millions of users)?

**Making assumptions here are my thoughts.....**

**Time**

If you want to do this task correctly the first time then say **NO** to 30 days, if its a large application then it may take that long to just test it, let alone (re)write it.

**CodeIgniter**

Have you used CodeIgniter before? I suspect not if you're asking on here about how easy or difficult it might be. It will take you at least one project to get into a framework and start to use it correctly. You should always make a dummy application with a framework before starting any production work in it, even then your first batch of code inside the framework will have issues.

**Scalability**

The scalability issue is probably a null point, if its a new project going live then scalability and performance should not be an issue initially unless you have a) huge marketing budget and are expecting a lot of traffic or b) you are hosting it on shared server and expecting it to perform well.

**Summary**

I would push through with the 75% you have and fix the security issues you mention. Writing the rest of it with the bespoke code and Codeigniter will cause you more issues which you do not know about yet, these will be harder to control, manage and fix. Fix the known security issues, these you can manage, control and fix. Codeigniter may open a whole new can of bugs for you.

**Ignore all of the above and do this**

Be honest with the the client, tell them 30 days is a no no and would be irresponsible of you to launch in such a rush. Explain about the security issues and why starting again with Codeigniter using the knowledge gained so far will produce a far superior application / web site.

Comment: @jakenbole I used Codeigniter before but not an EXPERT. 30 days to MVP release not the whole website itself. Scalable to 10,000 people and they may add lot of features to the existing project. I am taking your words. I will go with PHP instead of codeigniter as everything is developed. The previous developer left no comments in the code and I hope that wont be a problem.

Comment: You should already know the answer then - my last point 'Ignore all of the above and do this'.

Comment: This has happened to me before. Wash your hands of the old code, fix it and go live. But you must educate them on why this is a stupid decision. You should also get it in writing that you are not responsible for the existing code base. You should really tell them to go jump. Or add a zero to your fee.